# MYSQL CDC using apache Kafka and kafka connect on my local without using docker and confluent

Tags: mysql, rest, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

What is the best way to run a Kafka cluster on a server without docker and confluent cloud for CDC

how do i connect mysql db to kafka cluster running on local and create a sink connection to another mysql db.

i see REST API is the best way but not sure how to do it.

do i need to run the configuration on the producer end ?  need  some idea how to implement it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from MySQL does not require Confluent products.

Debezium is open-source, Apache 2.0 License. So is Kafka and Kafka Connect (which Debezium uses).

Kafka Connect [has a REST API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#connect), yes, that is the way to use it.

[The Debezium tutorial](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/tutorial.html) uses MySQL and Docker, but all steps can be repeated without Docker:

- Download Kafka
- Download Debezium Connectors and MySQL drivers and setup Connect classpath + plugins (follow the Debezium installation docs)
- Start Zookeeper and Kafka and Connect Distributed Server (follow the Kafka quickstart and Connect docs above, and use **distributed mode**)
- Reconfigure the database address & HTTP-POST the JSON mentioned in the tutorial to start the CDC Connector

To **sink** the data to another database, you will want to try to use [Confluent's JDBC Sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/index.html)

Comment: Will i be able to implement this without docker on a local machine using debezium connector   i was able to start the zookeeper and the kafka server locally if i have to connect kafka connect mysql connector how am i supposed to configure the properties of the kafka server. its pretty challenging but it should possible by some means right ?

Comment: By default, every Kafka process is configured for localhost connections correctly. You don't need to touch the broker settings to configure Kafka Connect / Debezium; it has its own properties files

Comment: yeah i did work that out but I couldn't add the mysql plugins when i try to start the standalone kafka connect it gets errored when it tries to add the plugin for mysql connector in debezium does it had to do anything with the latest version of kafka or the specifications of the machine ?

Comment: Java works on any machine, so no. Please edit your question to include what steps you've taken

Comment: i started the zookeeper, kafka and also the kafka standalone connect. But when i add the plugin path and restart the kafka connect i get error when the jar file is added ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:126)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/util/IoUtil

Comment: i think its because of the version i am using mysql8 but the debezium-connector is mysql 9.2  may be that's an issue?

Comment: Your error is saying that the Debezium connector jars are not installed properly, nothing to do with the mysql driver version (yet)

Comment: i was able to fix that error it was about the path i pointed it inside the mysql-connector file but now i get couple of new errors

Comment: Error: KAFKA_STORAGE_ERROR (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:615)
[2022-01-25 11:51:39,257] WARN [Producer clientId=connector-producer-mysql-connector-0] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition test-0 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Disk error when trying to access log file on the disk.. Going to request metadata update now (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:648)    ----- this is the error i get when kafka connect tries to snapshot

Comment: @Rooban Since you've been able to install and start a connector process, I consider this question as closed. Please create a new post for new errors. I will point out that your error might be related to file permissions, or that using Windows is not really supported for Kafka, if that's what you're using